# Compress Image size and return image c#

Tags: c#, image, compression, image-size

I am making a function where I pass an Image and that will compress the image and return that image object. Following is my code:

```
public Image CompressImage(Image img)
{
    ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = null;
    EncoderParameter imageQualitysParameter = new EncoderParameter(
                System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 50L);
    ImageCodecInfo[] alleCodecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

    EncoderParameters codecParameter = new EncoderParameters(1);
    codecParameter.Param[0] = imageQualitysParameter;
    for (int i = 0; i < alleCodecs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (alleCodecs[i].MimeType == "image/jpeg")
        {
            jpegCodec = alleCodecs[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    Image img1;
    using (Stream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(memory, jpegCodec, codecParameter);
        img1 = Image.FromStream(memory);
        memory.Close();
        memory.Dispose();
    }
    return img1;
}
```

But When I am saving it in the memory stream, it is showing error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EnexolImageConversionApp.exe
>
> Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

on line

```
img.Save(memory, jpegCodec, codecParameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code - it selects proper `ImageCodecInfo` by comparing `ImageFormat.Guid` and `ImageCodecInfo.FormatID`:

```
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.IO;

    public static byte[] SaveImageToByteArray(Image image, int jpegQuality = 90)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var jpegEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)jpegQuality);
            image.Save(ms, jpegEncoder, encoderParameters);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Last step will be loading image again from received byte array.
For better issue understanding please provide exception details, including stacktrace.

Comment: Same Error Occured agains. I think it s due to unhandling of memory stream. Image is not properly save in memory stream.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

Comment: @muhammad-nabeel did you try to save image without altering `encoderParameters `, or even just using `Image.Save(Stream stream)` ?